# java - iterate collection and call method for each iteration or pass collection to the method and iterate it

Tags: java, performance, memory, stack

I have a method which is called for each iteration of a collection ,accepts single element from a collection,  do some processing by creating some local variables and calls few external methods.

i want to understand if i update the method to receive the collection itself and then iterate inside the method and do the processing , how much performance difference it would have . As i understand in the first approach it , for each iteration there would be overhead of method calls which would create and destroy block in memory stack.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to measure the impact.

Comment: thanks for the response, will check the @Jakub Moravec response

Comment: For all we know, the compiler could wind up inlining the method (where the method call is replaced with the actual contents of the method, removing the need to call a method). What you shoud focus on is readability: which is easier to maintain for you? If a bug popped up in a large code base, which style would be easier for you to traverse and maintain? Creating a method for that specific piece of logic may make that logic easier to find in a larger code base.

Answer (score 1):

Performance gain is going to be equal to cost of calling a function, i.e. 
fraction of nanosecond per call. That is below level of noise for most measurement. Thinking about such small gains is usually not worth it, even in most high-perfomance setting.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java is a high-level programming language, method calls overheads are not usually considered during optimizations. 
The only performance impact here, as I see it, could be if You managed to reuse objects created in that method You call. If these objects demand a lot of memory, it could be a notable change.

Comment: Thanks @JakubMoravec , will check in this direction